# how can I put 2 Stream inside a streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a query in firebase, but to bring all the information I need, I have to put two streams within the Stream builder.

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

  //Here I need to place two Streams, how could I do it
      stream: partnerRequest,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package, It provides function [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) which will allow you to combine multiple streams.

Here is an example.

The following example combines 2 streams ie. stream1 and stream2 with help of combiner function.

```
CombineLatestStream.combine2(
  stream1,
  stream2,
  (s1, s2) => CombinerFunction(...),
)
```

Here is a more detailed example

Let's say we have 2 streams A and B and both stream boolean value. Now we want our streamBuilder to output some data only when both the values are true or else show and error.

```
StreamBuilder<bool>(
  stream : CombineLatestStream.combine2(A,B,(a,b)=>a&b),
  builder:(context,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == true)
      return Text("Successful");
    else
      return Text("Some error");
  }
);
```

Now CombineLatestStream will only output data when there is data from both the streams. So once both the streams have data it will perform the combiner function(and function for our example) and output the result. Hence we get True only when both the stream A and B have True value and false if any stream is having False value

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP, and I am trying to use CombineLatestStream, however I can't get the ConnectionState to change to active, it's always None, do you have an example?

Comment: Can you provide the stream or the query you are trying to use?

Comment: I am just looking for a full example of how to use CombineLatestStream and StreamBuilder. This is my original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61839711/restart-streambuilder-with-multiple-streams-after-connectionstate-done

Comment: If you could expand your answer to show how to use it in stream property of StreamBuilder, that would be helpful. I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Check out this [post](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxdart-magical-transformations-of-streams/) for a detailed explanation of Stream transformation. I will update my answer to show how it will be used in StreamBuilder.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question as well, I will check it out.

Comment: Getting error "The operator '&' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try adding a null check to the target ('!')." when I use of `a&b` in `stream : CombineLatestStream.combine2(A,B,(a,b)=>a&b),` statement. any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Its because of null safety, you can user `CombineLatestStream.combine2(A,B,(a,b)=>a!&b!)`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two stream builder as messy way such as below. But remember to change snapshot names to avoid confuse.

```
  StreamBuilder(
        stream: stream1,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: stream2,
            builder: (context, snapshot2) {
```

Comment: I tried to do something like this, the problem is that I need to put the information of both in a single ListView builder

Comment: You can do that, just define snapshot.data.id or something from first stream and snapshot2.data.name from second stream. Use both in anywhere you want with this way.

Comment: @Lunedor I am doing research on `StreamZip`, `StreamGroup.merge` and `CombineLatestStream.combine2`. If none of them works then this is the last solution to implement. Thanks dear.

Comment: BTW if stream1 has some issue then stream2 will definitely not work.

Comment: That's why I called it messy way but maybe that can be bypass with some if else condition, I need to try to be sure.