# Restart StreamBuilder with multiple streams after ConnectionState.done

Tags: flutter, dart

What's a good way when you want to use multiple streams in a StreamBuilder, to restart StreamBuilder to use the next stream?

Right now, I am checking if the stream is completed by using setState on a flag (_streamCompleted).

But I was wondering if it's possible to reuse the StreamBuilder after ConnectionState.done is fired.

```
 Stream donwloadStream = response.stream.map(processDownload);
```

...

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _streamIndex == null ? null : streams[_streamIndex].stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {

      if (ConnectionState.done) {
        // How do I switch to the next stream here ???
      }
```

This is how I am checking if completed:

```
double processDownload(List<int> chunk) {
    bytes.addAll(chunk);
    cnt = bytes.length;
    double progress = cnt / streams[_streamIndex].contentLength;

    if (cnt / streams[_streamIndex].contentLength == 1) {
      setState(() {           
          _streamCompleted = true;
          _streamIndex++;
      });
    }
     return progress;
 }
```

I have also tried using CombineLatestStream, but couldn't get the streams to start firing, ConnectionState is none.

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: _combinedStreams == null ? null : _combinedStreams,

    setState(() {
      _combinedStreams =
          CombineLatestStream.list([streams[0].stream, streams[1].stream, streams[2].stream])
              .asBroadcastStream();
    });

  _combinedStreams.listen((event) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use two stream builder.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _streamIndex == null ? null : streams[_streamIndex].stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (ConnectionState.done) {
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: _stream2 == null ? null : streams2.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot2) {...
```

Comment: Thanks, I know nested builders work, but the problem is I have an unkown number of streams, so would rather not go with this solution.